# can't import kornia.augmentation.functional

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, kornia

I have installed kornia and imorting it like,

```
from kornia.color import *
import kornia.augmentation.functional as F_k
import kornia as K
```

but the second line is giving error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kornia.augmentation.functional'.
```

Also, this is my directory structure.

[image: directory]

But I getting error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FewShot_models'
```

when I try to import `from FewShot_models.manipulate import *`.
I am following a code from github and trying to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kornia.augmentation.functional` was removed in version [0.5.4](https://github.com/kornia/kornia/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#054---2021-06-11) and the most of the functions are available through `kornia.augmentation`.

Regarding your second question, you need to add empty file named `__init__.py` to FewShot_models directory. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for details about `__init__.py`.